# cURL upload files to remote server on MS Windows

Tags: php, windows, linux, curl, upload

When I use linux and try upload file to remote server using this script then all is well. But if i use Windows then script not working.
Script:

```
$url="http://site.com/upload.php";
$post=array('image'=>'@'.getcwd().'images/image.jpg');
$this->ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$body = curl_exec($this->ch);
echo $body; // << on Windows empty result
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

PHP 5.3

Windows 7 - not working, Ubuntu Linux 10.10 - working

Comment: Do you have cURL compiled in to your PHP installation on your windows server?  Show the error message given.  You can check the installation via a [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) script.

Comment: Error not shown. (error_reporting = on)

Comment: getcwd() does not return with a slash on the end, so I'm missing that one, besides that shouldn't you use a backslash on windows instead of a forwardslash?

Comment: CURLOPT_VERBOSE: TRUE to output verbose information. Writes output to STDERR, or the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Error in log:

*** failed creating formpost data**

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows, your file path separator will be `\` not the Linux style `/`.

One obvious thing to try is

```
$post=array('image'=>'@'.getcwd().'images\image.jpg');
```

And see if that works.

If you want to make your script portable so it will work on with Windows or Linux, you can use [PHP's predefined constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

```
$post=array('image'=>'@'.getcwd().'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'image.jpg');
```

Comment: Nice answer. getting some thing new.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, your code should not work(i mean upload) in any, unix or windows. Consider this portion from your code:

```
'image'=>'@'.getcwd().'images/image.jpg'
```

In windows `getcwd()` returns `F:\Work\temp`
In Linux It returns `/root/work/temp`

So, your above code will compile like below:

Windows: `'image'=>'@F:\Work\tempimages/image.jpg'`
Linux: `'image'=>'@/root/work/tempimages/image.jpg'`

Since you mentioned it worked for you in linux, which means `/root/work/tempimages/image.jpg` somehow existed in your filesystem.

My PHP version:
Linux: `PHP 5.1.6`
Windows: `PHP 5.3.2`

Comment: Yes this is observable. nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `var_dump($body)` to see what `$body` really contains. With the way you configured cURL, `$body` will contain either the response by the server or false, on failure. There is no way to differentiate between an empty response or false with `echo`. It's possible the request is going through just fine, and the server is just returning nothing.

However, as others have said, your file path seems invalid. `getcwd()` does not output a final `/` and you will need to add one to make the code work. Since you said it works on linux, even without the missing slash, I am wondering how it is finding your file.

I would suggest you create a path to the file relative to the PHP script that is running, or provide an absolute path and not rely on `getcwd()` which probably does not return what you are expecting. The value of `getcwd()` can be unpredictable across systems and is not very portable.

For example, if the file you are trying to POST resides in the same folder as your PHP script:

`$post = array('image' => '@image.jpg');` is sufficient. If needed, provide an absolute path: `$post = array('image' => '@/home/youruser/yourdomain/image.jpg');`

As Terence said, if you need your code to be portable across Linux & Windows, consider using [PHP's Predefined Constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

```
$url = "http://yoursite.com/upload.php";
// images\image.jpg on Windows images/image.jpg on Linux
$post = array('image' => '@images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'image.jpg');
$this->ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$body = curl_exec($this->ch);
var_dump($body);
```

[getcwd()](https://www.php.net/getcwd) [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

if working with xampp
 Make sure that in php.ini configuration file

Line number 952 is uncommented 
   i.e
   if line is

```
   ;extension=php_curl.dll
```

then make it

```
  extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: The curl is working but there was the error the different error.

Answer (score 1):

I think, a better approach would be:

```
$imgpath = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(getcwd(), 'images', 'image.jpg'));
$post = array('image'=>'@'.$imgpath);
```